# Prevent logging with annotation

Tags: java, logging, aspect

In one of my project I am using slf4j as logging facade.
I want to develop an annotation,which when applied on particular bean property should prevent it from logging.It should mask that property value with some value like "**************" only while logging.
Could anyone give me an idea on how to do it?
I tried it with spring AOP. In the pointcut expression I wrote an expression to invoke aspect before and after get method is called on bean property. But it ended up in vain.
Sample bean code is as follows

```
public class MyBean{
      private String property;

      public void setProperty(String property){
          this.property = property;
      }

      @NotLoggable   // This is the annotation which I should develop
      public String getProperty(){
           return property;
      }
  }
```

The aspect is to be applied only when get* method annotated with `@NotLoggable` is called inside logger methods like error(), warn()...e.t.c

Or else, if I could apply the annotation on field(property) like following code and if it got prevented from logging, that is also fine.

```
public class MyBean {

      @NotLoggable   // This is the annotation which I should develop
      private String property;

      public void setProperty(String property){
          this.property = property;
      }


      public String getProperty(){
           return property;
      }
  }
```

Are there any alternatives for this?

Could aspectj helps me?